# PHP connection to SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I need to connect from PHP to an SQL Server 2008 instance. The Webserver is Apache 2.4 on a Centos 8 with PHP 7.4, php-sqlsrv extension, and I am using PDO to handle the connection.
First I tested the connection from cli, and I got the following error:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol]

A little bit of googling sent me to a direction toward openssl.cnf, where I set the minimum version to TLS 1.0 (I know it's not secure, but it seemed to be working), and then connection worked, but only in cli, when I try it from the site, it still gives the same error.

The code I use for the connection is this (I changed the connection data):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=database.local,1433;Database=database", "user", "password");
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Can you help me figure out what I missed?

Thank you

Comment: The *real* question is why are you using a SQL Server 2008 instance? It's been completely unsupported for almost 2 years now. TLS 1.2, however, is available on SQL Server 2008 and I suggest you make the efforts to use it. [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe)

Comment: PHP is most likely using it's own [builtin OpenSSL library](https://www.php.net/openssl). I've no idea of how configurable is it.

Comment: The driver version you're using doesn't support SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the administrator of the DB server, so I have no say in its configuration whatsoever :(

Comment: [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server® - Windows, Linux, & macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339) was the last driver to officially support SQL Server 2008. If you can't upgrade the server then downgrade the client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.